# Jquery поиск в DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую, сложилась такая проблема:
не могу найти элемент и взять его параметр. 
Элемент с атрибутом: `lang-change="ru"`
К примеру: `<span lang-change="ru">Text</span>`
Если бы это было `data-lang="ru"`, то поиск не составил бы труда.

Comment: [немного справки](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй так:

```
console.log($('[lang-change="ru"]'));
```

Comment: второй вариант не находит, а выставляет всем элементам span этот атрибут в значение `ru`